# Will nodes from different layers interact

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2, game-physics

I have added various layers to a GameScene (GS) (i.e. HUD, scores layers). I have also added a layer to hold and manage projectiles spawned from a Player entity (main layer).

Problem is although I have set collision and category bitmasks for all nodes in all layers the projectile does not interact with any nodes in the main layer of the GS.

So question is will nodes interact with each other if they are contained within different layers of a GS?

Thanks in advance

PS All nodes are Entities with sprite and physics components

Comment: Keep in mind that if you are interested in physics interaction, at least one physics body has to be dynamic. So make a `projectile.physicsBody.dynamic = true`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, everything will work as usual no matter if your nodes having the same parent or have been arranged into multiple nodes (parents, layers, call them as you like)... Thing you may find useful to know, is that node tree (this is where nodes live) is separate from physics world (this is where physics bodies live).

Comment: Thanks, the good news is now I understand and bad is I don't no why there's no interaction, both nodes have physics bodies and collision / category bitmasks set against one another, but no interaction. The projectile is the only node that doesn't interact with other nodes in tej GS

Comment: Will the physics world of the gamescene apply to all child layers?

Comment: @dancingbush Likely because you haven't set category, contact and collision bit masks properly. Or because you haven't set physics world delegate or you made some other error. But that is another topic and you should ask a new question...

Comment: @dancingbush As I said. Look at the physics world as a separate thing where physics bodies live. In that world, physics engine applies forces and impulses to them, and based on that, node's position is updated accordingly ... So, yes, again. All nodes that have physics bodies attached will be affected by physics simulation if their `physicsBody.dynamic property` is set to true.

Comment: Many thanks, will go and have another look, will update if / when I find a solution

Comment: @dancingbush Have you had success with other SK projects getting contacts and collsiions to work or is this your first?

Comment: @SteveIves yes all other nodes within the GS interact under a 'worldLayer', but the one node (projectile) in a LayerProjectile will not interact with any nodes in GS

Comment: @SteveIves yes, one SK project in obj c but that was some years ago

Comment: Have posted extended Question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41642575/nodes-in-a-scene-from-different-layers-will-not-interact