# Nodes in a Scene from different layers will not interact

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2, collision-detection, game-physics

Apologies in advance as this Question involves allot of code.
I have a GameScene with multiple layers holding Nodes/SpriteNodes for HUD/Scores/ etc. One layer, LayerProjectile, holds a Weapon Entity.

Said Entity has both Sprite and Physics Components. 
Problem is the Projectile nodes in the LayerProjectile do not interact with nodes in the main layer (worldLayer), of the GameScene.

All physics bodies are dynamic, and the GameScene has its PhysicWorldDelgate

```
class GamePlayMode: SGScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {...
```

// Weapon Enity (SGEntity is a GKEntity)

class ThrowWeapon : SGEntity {

```
    var spriteComponent: SpriteComponent!
    var physicsComponent: PhysicsComponent
    init(position: CGPoint, size: CGSize, texture:SKTexture){

            super.init();

            //Initilse Compnemnets
            spriteComponent = SpriteComponent(entity: self, texture: texture, size: size, position: position);
            addComponent(spriteComponent);
            physicsComponent = PhysicsComponent(entity: self, bodySize: CGSize(width: spriteComponent.node.size.width * 0.8, height: spriteComponent.node.size.height * 0.8), bodyShape: .square, rotation: true);
            physicsComponent.setCategoryBitmask(ColliderType.Projectile.rawValue, dynamic: true);
            physicsComponent.setPhysicsCollisions(ColliderType.None.rawValue);
            physicsComponent.setPhysicsContacts( ColliderType.Destroyable.rawValue | ColliderType.Enemy.rawValue);
            physicsComponent.setEffectedByGravity(false);
            addComponent(physicsComponent);

            //Final Steps of compnements
            spriteComponent.node.physicsBody = physicsComponent.physicsBody;
            spriteComponent.node.name = "weapon";
            name = "weapon";
            spriteComponent.node.zPosition = 150;

            spriteComponent.node.userData = ["startX" : position.x];
```

// Handle Contacts

override func contactWith(entity: SGEntity) {
        //If contact with Enity in GemeScene

```
    switch entity.name {

    case "destructableEntity":

        //Remove from Scsene  self.parent?.parent?.runAction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("110548__noisehag__comp-cover-02.wav", waitForCompletion: false))
        if let spriteComponentDestructable = entity.componentForClass(SpriteComponent.self){

            let pos = spriteComponentDestructable.node.position;

            spriteComponent.node.removeFromParent();


            spriteComponentDestructable.node.parent?.runAction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("110548__noisehag__comp-cover-02.wav", waitForCompletion: false));
            spriteComponentDestructable.node.removeAllActions();
            spriteComponentDestructable.node.removeFromParent();

            emitterExplosion(pos);

        }

       // self.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.fadeAlphaTo(0.0, duration: 0.5), SKAction.removeFromParent()]))
       break;
         case "enemyEntity":
        if let spriteComponentEnemy = entity.componentForClass(SpriteComponent.self){

                let pos = spriteComponentEnemy.node.position;

                spriteComponent.node.removeFromParent();
    spriteComponentEnemy.node.parent?.runAction(SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("110548__noisehag__comp-cover-02.wav", waitForCompletion: false));
                spriteComponentEnemy.node.removeAllActions();
               spriteComponentEnemy.node.removeFromParent();

                emitterExplosion(pos);

            } break;
      default:
        //
        break;
    }
```

LayerProjectile, which inherits from Layer- a SKNode, and which handles all weapon entities added to GameScene

```
class LayerProjectiles: Layer { 

        override func updateNodes(delta:CFTimeInterval,childNumber:Int,childNode: SKNode) {

print("Player movenment direction: \(playerMovingRighToLeft)");

            if playerMovingRighToLeft {

                // player moving to right so throw weapon same direction
                childNode.position = childNode.position + CGPoint(x: delta * -weaponSpeed, y: 0.0);
                childNode.zRotation = childNode.zRotation - (CGFloat(delta) * 10);



            } else{

            childNode.position = childNode.position + CGPoint(x: delta * weaponSpeed, y: 0.0)
            childNode.zRotation = childNode.zRotation - (CGFloat(delta) * 10)

            }


            // When arrow within this layer moves out of the screen remove it, and the reverse
            if childNode.position.x > ((childNode.userData!["startX"] as! CGFloat) + (SKMSceneSize!.width * 1.2)) || childNode.position.x < ((childNode.userData!["startX"]as! CGFloat) - (SKMSceneSize!.width * 1.2)){
                childNode.removeFromParent()
            }

        }
```

Adding Instance of LayerProjectile and worldLayer (holding all other nodes, some of which have catBitMask set to notify when contact with Weapon Entity), to the GameScene (an instance of GamePlayMode, a SGScene)

```
class GameSceneState: GKState {
  unowned let gs: GamePlayMode
  init(scene: GamePlayMode) {
    self.gs = scene
  }
}
gs.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = gs
    gs.physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: -1.0)
//Layers
    gs.layerProjectile = LayerProjectiles();
    gs.worldLayer = TileLayer(levelIndex: gs.levelIndex, typeIndex: .setMain)
    gs.backgroundLayer = SKNode()
    gs.overlayGUI = SKNode()
    gs.addChild(gs.worldLayer)
   gs.addChild(gs.layerProjectile);// For throwing wepaons, made in GamePlayMode
```

And finally the physics/sprite component settings for a Destrutable entity, which is a child of worldLayer (added to the GaemScene along with LayerProjectile)

```
    class Destructable : SGEntity{

        var spriteComponent: SpriteComponent!
        var animationComponent: AnimationComponent!
        var physicsComponent: PhysicsComponent!
        var scrollerComponent: FullControlComponent!

        init(position: CGPoint, size: CGSize, texture:SKTexture){

            super.init();

            //Initilse Compnemnets
            spriteComponent = SpriteComponent(entity: self, texture: texture, size: size, position: position);
            addComponent(spriteComponent);
            physicsComponent = PhysicsComponent(entity: self, bodySize: CGSize(width: spriteComponent.node.size.width * 0.8, height: spriteComponent.node.size.height * 0.8), bodyShape: .square, rotation: false);
            physicsComponent.setCategoryBitmask(ColliderType.Destroyable.rawValue , dynamic: true);
            physicsComponent.setPhysicsCollisions(ColliderType.Wall.rawValue | ColliderType.Player.rawValue | ColliderType.Destroyable.rawValue); // collides with so bpounces off
           physicsComponent.setPhysicsContacts(ColliderType.Wall.rawValue | ColliderType.Player.rawValue | ColliderType.Projectile.rawValue);
            physicsComponent.setEffectedByGravity(true);

            addComponent(physicsComponent);

            //Final Steps of compnements
            spriteComponent.node.physicsBody = physicsComponent.physicsBody;
            spriteComponent.node.name = "destructableEntity";
            name = "destructableEntity";
            spriteComponent.node.zPosition = 150;

            //spriteComponent.node.userData = ["startX" : position.x];



        }

// Handle contacts
 override func contactWith(entity: SGEntity) {
        // 
        if entity.name == "weapon"{

            print("Crate hit Projectile");
    }


}
```

Instantionation of the Weapon Projectile (when user hits throw button during game play) and Destructible Entities when initializing GameScene and adding all sprite nodes:

```
let throwWeapon = ThrowWeapon(position: CGPoint(x: self.spriteComponent.node.position.x, y: self.spriteComponent.node.position.y + (self.spriteComponent.node.size.height / 2)), size: CGSize(width: 9, height: 40),  texture: textureAtlas.textureNamed("kunai"));

        playerEnt.gameScene.layerProjectile.addChild(throwWeapon.spriteComponent.node);
```

// Destructible Entity

```
gs.worldLayer.enumerateChildNodesWithName("placeholder_Destructable")  { (node, stop) -> Void in
        let crate = Destructable(position:  node.position, size: CGSize(width: 32, height: 32),  texture: tileAtlasInstance.textureNamed("Crate"));
        //crate.name = "placeholder_Destructable";
        //crate.spriteComponent.node.zPosition = GameSettings.GameParams.zValues.zWorldFront;
        self.gs.addEntity(crate, toLayer: self.gs.worldLayer)
    }
```

Any input appreciated.

Added: Category bitmask enum for ColliderTypes:

```
enum ColliderType:UInt32 {
  case Player        = 0
  case Destroyable   = 0b1
  case Wall          = 0b10
  case Collectable   = 0b100 // get points
  case EndLevel      = 0b1000
  case Projectile    = 0b10000
  case None          = 0b100000
  case KillZone      = 0b1000000
  case arrow         = 0b10000000;
  case fire =          0b100000000; // die
  case blueFire =      0b1000000000; // die
  case greenCrystal =  0b10000000000; //more points like collectables
  case barrel1 =       0b100000000000; //die
  case barrell2 =      0b1000000000000; //die
  case swordPoints =   0b10000000000000; //points
  case spikes =        0b100000000000000; //die
  case Enemy =         0b1000000000000000; // see Eneemy Entity


    // against arrow and fire

}
```

// The SGEnity class where func handling physics contacts for Enities are called and overridden in Entity (Weapon, Destructible) classes

class SGEntity: GKEntity {

var name = ""

func contactWith(entity:SGEntity) {
    //Overridden by subclass

}

// PhyscisComponent

```
enum PhysicsBodyShape {
  case square
    case squareOffset;// so the player knowns where the tile physics body is
  case circle
  case topOutline
  case bottomOutline
}

class PhysicsComponent: GKComponent {

  var physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody()

  init(entity: GKEntity, bodySize: CGSize, bodyShape: PhysicsBodyShape, rotation: Bool) {

    switch bodyShape {
    case.square:
      physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bodySize)
      break
    case.squareOffset:
      physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: bodySize, center: CGPoint(x: 0, y: bodySize.height/2 + 2))
      break
    case .circle:
      physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: bodySize.width / 2)
      break
    case .topOutline:
      physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeFromPoint: CGPoint(x: (bodySize.width/2) * -1, y: bodySize.height/2), toPoint: CGPoint(x: bodySize.width/2, y: bodySize.height/2))
      break
    case .bottomOutline:
      physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeFromPoint: CGPoint(x: (bodySize.width/2) * -1, y: (bodySize.height/2) * -1), toPoint: CGPoint(x: bodySize.width/2, y: (bodySize.height/2) * -1))
      break
    }

    physicsBody.allowsRotation = rotation




    //Defaults
    physicsBody.dynamic = true
    physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.None.rawValue
    physicsBody.collisionBitMask = ColliderType.None.rawValue
  }



  func setCategoryBitmask(bitmask:UInt32, dynamic: Bool) {

    physicsBody.categoryBitMask = bitmask
    physicsBody.dynamic = dynamic

  }

  func setPhysicsCollisions(bitmask:UInt32) {

    physicsBody.collisionBitMask = bitmask

  }

  func setPhysicsContacts(bitmask:UInt32) {

    physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = bitmask

  }

    func setEffectedByGravity (gravity: Bool){
        physicsBody.affectedByGravity = gravity;
    }

}
```

So, contactsBegan is called via PhysicsDelage of the GameScene, :

```
if let bodyA = contact.bodyA.node as? EntityNode, //SpriteNode
      let bodyAent = bodyA.entity as? SGEntity,       // COnverted to SGEntity
      let bodyB = contact.bodyB.node as? EntityNode, //SprtiteNode
      let bodyBent = bodyB.entity as? SGEntity //ERROR HERE : Cast to SGEnity

    {
        print("SGENity Description: \(bodyBent)");
        contactBegan(bodyAent, nodeB: bodyBent)
        contactBegan(bodyBent, nodeB: bodyAent)
    }else{
        print("Cast error")
    }
```

Issue appears to be casting the Projectile Entity to a SGEntity, this fails and contactsWith... of Projectile Entity is never called. All other SGEnities (Destructible) cast to SGEntity with no issues.,...

Comment: First of all, are you positive that your ColliderType has categories properly set ? Eg. 1,2,4... rather than 1,2,3 ? And as I said in your previous question, check if at least one body is dynamic - means, if your projectile collides with destroyable object, at least one of them has to be dynamic.

Comment: Yep have set projectile and destructible nodes to Dynamic, have posted Category bit masks to question

Comment: Categories seems fine. So you maybe you are handling contacts  (didBeginContact method) incorrectly...

Comment: Also there is `physicsComponent.setPhysicsCollisions(ColliderType.None.rawValue);` in your ThrowWeapon entity, which is I guess a projectile. It will not collide with anything.

Comment: Yup thats a old ver, have updated, and added PhysicsComponent class, SGEntity parent class for Enities, and contact handling func of physics bodies for Weapon Projectile and Destructible neity

Comment: When I see this :  case "destructableEntity":, the first thought came on my mind was - typo :) Use constants if you are reusing the same string. Now, put a break point in a method that handle contacts between projectile and destructable object and see at which point it fails. Also are you positive that all your entities have names set?

Comment: Yep all spelling checks out and all entities have names. Have set breakpoint in contact func of Projectile- problem is it is never called for Projectile Entity, but is for tej destructible when it contacts a player Entity, stumped

Comment: I can't see a part where you handle contact between projectile & destructable actually, but if it isn't called, then you should double-check your contact & category bit masks on these objects. I don't know what else to say. There is a lot of code, so maybe I am missing something.

Comment: One question...Where do you handle contacts actually ? Which class implements didBeginContact & didEndContact methods? EDIT: oh I see...You handle contacts in each entity , right? What triggers that contactWith:(entity:) method? I mean where in your code you have something like didBeginContact which is invoked automatically by the physics engine?

Comment: Made me go back and have a look, said func are called in the GameScene via the Physicsdelegate and handled in each SGEntity,  and I discovered an issue when casting the Projectile SKSpriteNode to a SGEntity fails, hence the contactsWith(SGEntity) is never called in the Projectile....see updated Question

Comment: Put a break point and see why casting fails.

Comment: @Whirlwind Thanks for pointing me right direction, issue was I was adding the projectiles spritecomponment.node to the LayerPorjectile, when I should of been adding the Projectile Entity , the cast failed because the Projectile node naturally had no entity member and could not be Cast to a SGENtity, thanks again

Comment: Nice. Glad to hear you figured it out by yourself. Happy coding :)